# How to translate dates in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation, django-i18n

I've read documentation, I put i18n in top and tried to translate date variables by:

```
{%  blocktrans %}
                   {{ month_verbose }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

But it doesn't work, also I want to translate month_verbose to current language.
I don't know how to combine current language with translation with dates.
So what is the best way to translate dates in django templates?

UPD
[View for this template](https://github.com/doubledare704/djangt/blob/master/students/views/journal.py) Var month verbose is on 39th row
[Template here](https://github.com/doubledare704/djangt/blob/master/students/templates/students/vidviduv.html) month verbose on 33rd row

Comment: You have mistake in script `{% block trans %}{{ month_verbose}}{% endblock %}`

Comment: You'll want to have a look at django template builtins https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy, i thought it's like in docs [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans)

Comment: @shmee, it only formats date type in different view. I want to translate month verbose to another lang, default is English.

Comment: Where does `month_verbose` come from?

Comment: And what other language? That of the server? Or that of the user agent?

Comment: @DerekKwok, it goes from TemplateView of its get_context_data in context['month_verbose'] = month.strftime('%B')

Comment: @shmee, ukrainian, It's detected by django with Accept-Language HTTP header. So it's a client's lang

Comment: In line 39 of journal.py, remove the `strftime` call, and use a `date` filter in your template. This will cause the field to be localized automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

You can remove the `blocktrans` tags. Django `date` filter values are localized automatically when `USE_L10N=True`, so there's no need to use `localize` template tag or filter.

```
# prints out "uk"
{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }} 

# prints out "Січ"
{{ month_verbose|date:"M" }}
```

Comment: DATETIME_FORMAT is not set in settings and this code have no changes for translation in another language

Comment: I've added some updates to the answer. Also, do you have `USE_L10N = True` in your settings.py?

Comment: yes, it is set and in template l10n is also set, last your modification in code has bad result: month verbose disappear because of date filter. Month-verbose already contains only month textual format.

Comment: You need to pass `month_verbose` directly into your template - as a python datetime object. What is the current `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`? If you change that value, does the localization work?

Comment: Do you have LocaleMiddleware installed? `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware`

Comment: LANGUAGE_CODE = 'uk' and it's not changing. Yes, this middleware is installed in templates var.